# Matlab tic toc accuracy

Tags: performance, matlab, profiling

I'm measuring some code in loop

```
fps = zeros(1, 100);
for i=1:100

    t = tic
    I = fetch_image_from_source(); % function to get image
    fps(i) = 1./ toc(t);

end
plot(fps);
```

And I get average 50 fps.

Then I'd like to add `imshow()` to my code. I understand that `imshow` is very slow, but I won't include `imshow` inside `tic-toc` commands:

```
fps = zeros(1, 100);
figure;
for i=1:100

    t = tic
    I = fetch_image_from_source(); % function to get image
    fps(i) = 1./ toc(t);

    imshow(I); drawnow;

end
plot(fps);
```

And I get fps about 20%-30% slower. Why does it happen? Because `imshow()` is outside `tic-toc`

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? Are these results consistent? If so, try disabling JIT acceleration with `feature accel off` before running this and see if it's reproducible.

Comment: Also try using FRAPS for frame rate measurements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [matlab's doc](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/improvements-to-tic-and-toc-functions-for-measuring-absolute-elapsed-time-performance-in-matlab.html) about time in general and how elapsed time was and is currently measured in matlab. We can read that "*tic and toc [offers] the highest accuracy and most predictable behavior*". I think it is valid statement.

The drop of performance observed here is not due to a bad measure of elapsed time, and not related either to the use of `imshow` or `drawnow` functions. I will argue that it is related to a cache system.

The figure below displays the results of four tests, each of them having its own `tic/toc` baseline measure (plotted in blue) for 100 iterations. The green line shows the performance in different conditions:

```
(1)    for ii=1:100
         t = tic;                %single tic/toc
         fps(ii,2) = 1./toc(t); 
         rand(1000);             %extra function outside tic/toc
       end
```

As reported in your question, we can observe a slower frame per second (FPS; I would say 30%) despite `rand` being outside of the tic/toc block. The extra function can be of any type (`plot`, `surf`, `imshow`, `sum`), you will always observe a performance drop.

```
(2)    for ii=1:100
         t = tic;                %first tic/toc
         fps(ii,2) = 1./toc(t); 
         t = tic;                %second tic/toc
         fps(ii,2) = 1./toc(t);
         rand(1000);             %extra function outside tic/toc
       end
```

In the second subplot, the tic/toc block is repeated twice. The `fps` measurement is therefore executed two times and only the second measure is kept. We see that the performance drop is not there anymore - just like the first tic/toc call prepared the second one (warm-up). I interpret this in term of cache: the instructions and/or data are executed and then kept in a low level memory - the second call is faster.

```
(3)    for ii=1:100
         t = tic;                     %first tic/toc
         fps(ii,2) = 1./toc(t);
         for ij = 1:10000             %10,000 extra tic/toc
           tic;
           tmp = toc;
         end
       end
```

The third subplot used 10,000 tic/toc as an extra function in a single call scenario. You can see the the performance is nearly identical. The whole set of data/instructions in this subplot is only related to tic/toc - again, with a fast cache access.

```
(4)    for ii=1:100               %first tic/toc block
         t = tic;   
         fps(ii,1) = 1./toc(t);
       end
       for ii=1:100               %second tic/toc block
         t = tic;   
         fps(ii,2) = 1./toc(t);
       end
```

Finally, the fourth subplot shows two consecutive block of tic/toc calls. We can see that the second one performs better than the first one (a warm-up effect).

The overall pattern shown here is not related to `imshow`, does not depend on `JIT` of `accel`, but depends only on successive calls to a particular function. I interpret this in terms of cache, but I lack some kind of formal evidence.

Here are the plots

[image]

and the code

```
%% EXTRA FUNCTION (single call)
fps = zeros(2, 100);

% first case: 100 tic/toc
for ii=1:100
    t = tic;   
    fps(ii,1) = 1./toc(t);
end

%second case: 100 tic/toc + additional function
for ii=1:100

    t = tic;   
    fps(ii,2) = 1./toc(t);

    % graph or scalar functions (uncomment to test)
    %drawnow;
    %plot(1:10)
    rand(1000);          
    %ones(1000, 1000);
    %sum(1:1000000);
    %diff(1:1000000);
end


h = figure('Color','w','Position',[10 10 600 800]);

subplot(4,1,1);
plot(fps); legend({'tic/toc only','extra function'});
ylabel('FPS');
title('extra function, single call','FontSize',14);
set(gca,'FontSize',14, 'YLim', [0 3.5e5]);

%% EXTRA FUNCTION (double call)
fps = zeros(2, 100);

% first case: 100 tic/toc
for ii=1:100
    t = tic;   
    fps(ii,1) = 1./toc(t);
end

%second case: 100 tic/toc + additional function (except tic/toc)
for ii=1:100

    %first call
    t = tic;   
    fps(ii,2) = 1./toc(t);

    %second call (identical to first)
    t = tic;   
    fps(ii,2) = 1./toc(t);

    rand(1000);
end

subplot(4,1,2);
plot(fps); legend({'tic/toc only','extra function'});
ylabel('FPS');
title('extra function, double call','FontSize',14);
set(gca,'FontSize',14, 'YLim', [0 3.5e5]);


%% EXTRA FUNCTION (double call)
fps = zeros(2, 100);

% first case: 100 tic/toc
for ii=1:100
    t = tic;   
    fps(ii,1) = 1./toc(t);
end

%second case: 100 tic/toc + 10000 tic/toc
for ii=1:100

    t = tic;   
    fps(ii,2) = 1./toc(t);

    for ij = 1:10000
        tic;
        tmp = toc;
    end

end


subplot(4,1,3);
plot(fps); legend({'tic/toc','extra tic/toc'});
ylabel('FPS');
title('Identical function calls','FontSize',14);
set(gca,'FontSize',14, 'YLim', [0 3.5e5]);


%% TIC/TOC call twice
fps = zeros(2, 100);

% first case: 100 tic/toc
for ii=1:100
    t = tic;   
    fps(ii,1) = 1./toc(t);
end

for ii=1:100
    t = tic;   
    fps(ii,2) = 1./toc(t);
end

subplot(4,1,4);
plot(fps); legend({'tic/toc (1)','tic/toc (2)'});
ylabel('FPS');
title('tic/toc twice','FontSize',14);
set(gca,'FontSize',14, 'YLim', [0 3.5e5]);
```

Comment: +1: Interesting. I wonder if these tests be affected by `feature accel off`.

Comment: @Eitan T - these patterns are _not_ influenced by `feature('accel','off');` and `feature('JIT','off');`. But there might be another reason for the performance drop, as I don't have a method to say "instructions/data are stored in cache" - we only see the by-products here.

Comment: I understand that. Just shootin' in the dark here. You got points for the effort, nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to your processor's multi-threading capability.

The number of computational threads used by MATLAB is based on the value of [`maxNumCompThreads`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/maxnumcompthreads.html). If you set this to `1`, then both cases should theoretically yield the same fps.

You can do achieve this as:

```
LASTN = maxNumCompThreads(N);
```

Here `N` ought to be `1` and `LASTN` will give you the previous maximum number of computational threads, which may be useful later in case you want to reset the preference.

Comment: So why would this affect one case and not the other?

Comment: @EitanT: I don't have access to MATLAB to confirm right now, but I'm guessing that the `imshow` may be taken care of by additional threads coming into play.

Comment: I still don't understand how that would account for the _slowdown_ caused by adding `imshow`...

Comment: From documentation of this method: `"Note:   maxNumCompThreads will be removed in a future version. You can set the -singleCompThread option when starting MATLAB to limit MATLAB to a single computational thread. By default, MATLAB makes use of the multithreading capabilities of the computer on which it is running."`

And when I call this function, it returns 4.

Comment: @EitanT: Just guessing here, but it could be that the JIT is smart enough (or stupid enough) to offload the `imshow` to a separate thread, and the call to `fetch_image_from_source` to a separate thread, but keeps the `tic/toc` in the main thread. This would imply that the overhead of starting the thread and transferring the data for the `fetch_image_from_source`-thread adds up on each iteration.

Comment: @Innuendo: Does the slowdown still happen when you set it to 1 core?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I'd say it's a long shot but if this is the case, then the tic/toc measurement would be way off as `toc` yields a measurement _before_ the background threads are finished, right?

Comment: @EitanT: Well, if it is the case, the `toc` would need to wait until the thread finishes to maintain code coherency (compiled code should do the same as un-compiled). This would imply a `join` before the call to `toc`. Any decent compiler could generate this sort of thing. Whether or not to do it is a design choise, and if the OP's single-core performance indeed differs from his multi-core performance, well, I guess TMW must have chosen something similar to this path :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis So you're saying that `toc` follows a thread-join, and the measurement difference reflects the overhead of thread-creation/context-switching? And this is the reason for a 20%-30% difference? Maybe, but that's quite a stretch. Doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @EitanT: No, it doesn't. I'll stop here and not try to rescue my brainfart with more counter-arguments: chances are that probably something else is going on :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Actually I was thinking that both `imshow` and `drawnow` hog CPU resources, effectively slowing down further execution. I'd try removing `drawnow` and see if it affects measurements at all.

Comment: @EitanT: still, how should that affect what `tic`/`toc` measures?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Perhaps this just makes MATLAB run plain slower, _e.g_ it gobbles RAM and forces MATLAB to use virtual memory instead...

Comment: @EitanT: For humongous images and/or very old computers, that could indeed make sense...However, I doubt that RAM is not cleared after the call to `imshow`, in other words, that call should *not* affect load times of the image, regardless of any disk use by either `imshow` or `fetch_image_from_source`...Unless clearing the page file is done while the loop continues (doubtful).

Comment: @EitanT: Has the term "brainstink" ever been coined anywhere? :)