# Matlab weird computation time

Tags: matrix, time, tableofcontents

I had a weird experience with Matlab. I wanted to compute the time needed for matrices multiplication as follows:

> tic;
>   for i=1:10^-3:10^4
>      [1 1 1]*[1 1 1;1 1 1;1 1 1];
>   end
>   toc;

and

> tic;
>   for i=1:10^-3:10^4
>      [1 1 1;1 1 1;1 1 1]*[1 1 1;1 1 1;1 1 1];
>   end
>   toc;

now the result for first one was

> Elapsed time is 7.707570 seconds.

so I expected the second one to be as 23 seconds (since the first one needs n^2=9 multiplications while the second one needs n^3=27) but the result was:

> Elapsed time is 10.558797 seconds.

can someone explain to me what happened here?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571744/matlab-tic-toc-accuracy

Comment: Similar results from timeit function so I don't think it's related to tic-toc accuracy

Comment: Well, at least that eliminates one option :)

Comment: Sorry, no definite answer. All I can suggest is that there is some caching, or optimizations on repeated identical calculations. One thing you could try is to create random matrices and see if you get similar results.